# How can I access the custom breakpoint override in Material UI v5?

Tags: material-ui

Could you please guide me on how to access the custom breakpoint override in Material UI v5?  the available values for the custom breakpoints showing as available  are

> xs: number, sm: number, md: number, lg: number, and xl: number.

However, I'm unsure about the specific steps or code required to access and utilize my diphone later(android) custom breakpoints... it appears that the theme is just not seeing theme.

```js
// Material UI Styled Component
const StyledAccordionDetails = styled(AccordionDetails)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  padding: 0,
  width: '100%',
  margin: 0,
  lineHeight: 'normal',
  [mediaQuery]: {
    marginLeft: '10px',
  },
  [`@media (min-width: ${theme.breakpoints.values.iPhone320}px)`]: {
    marginLeft: '18px',
  },
}));


// Overrides 
const breakpointsOverrides = {
  values: {
    xs: 0,
    sm: 600,
    md: 900,
    lg: 1200,
    xl: 1920, // Set xl to match Material UI v4 since it is better.
    // IOS devices  4 ---> 12
    iPhone320: 320, //'iPhone 4/SE/5/5s/5c'
    iPhone375: 375, //'iPhone 6/7/8/X/XS/11Pro/SE2'
    iPhone414: 414, // 'iPhone 6Plus/7Plus/8Plus/XR/11/XSMax/11ProMax'
    iPhone360: 360, //'iPhone 12 mini'
    iPhone390: 390, //'iPhone 12/12Pro'
    iPhone428: 428, //'iPhone 12 Pro Max'
  },
};
```